# How to hide outline around input range in WebKitGTK and WPE WebKit?

Tags: html, css, webkitgtk, wpe-webkit

[image: outline]

I have tested the following code, but it doesn't seem to be effective.

```css
input[type="range"],
::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

I am aware that the CSS appearance property allows us to hide the default appearance and apply custom styles. However, I am specifically looking for a way to hide only the outline without affecting the default appearance.

To run WebKitGTK, you can use Gnome Web on a Linux system, and for WPE WebKit, you can use [WPE Android](https://github.com/Igalia/wpe-android/releases/tag/latest-preview) on an Android device.

Comment: Have you tried writing two separate rulesets (one for the `input` element, and one for the track pseudo-element) instead of combining them as a selector list? Sometimes non-standard pseudo-elements don't play well in selector lists.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I tried using separate rulesets for the input element and the track pseudo-element, but unfortunately, neither of them produced the desired results.